# Should I add sudo before the fastboot command on macOS just like on Linux?

Tags: terminal, android, sudo

I will be using `fastboot` on macOS. I will be following t[his tutorial](https://forum.xda-developers.com/z2-play/how-to/stock-stock-firmware-t3630997).

The guide only mentions Windows and Linux, and I do not wish to install those on my Mac right now, and as I think `fastboot` is the same on all platforms, I figure I might just use macOS.

However, the guide says:

> Linux users will need to change the extension to .sh and add sudo
>   before each command or directly run it as root.

Does that apply on macOS also? Should I add `sudo` before each `fastboot` command?

Comment: The file extension has no meaning in Unix

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens? If it works without sudo: yay  If it works with sudo: yay

Comment: What @JBis said.  I don't see why this can't be attempted.  You have a 50/50 shot of getting it right on the first go.